# Could someone help clarify the meaning of this pre-calculus question on Binomial Expansion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm taking an online pre-calculus course and I'm currently working on a unit about Binomial expansion.

I've come across an oddly worded (at least to me) question on coefficients:

> "What coefficient will yield the coefficient of the term $x^{10}+y^5$  in the expansion of $(x+y)^{15}$?"

I thought it just meant what was the coefficient of the term in the expansion, so I tried entering $$3003 x^{10} y^5$$
but it wouldn't accept it as an answer. Could someone clarify what exactly this question is asking?

Comment: It *is* oddly worded: the term is $x^{10}y^5$, not $x^{10}+y^5$. And "What coefficient will yield the coefficient..." is beyond odd. I would just try entering the coefficient 3003 (if that is indeed correct: I have not calculated it). Or maybe look for another course...

Comment: I'll try to enter that. This is for school credit and I'm in too deep. Can't stop now...but I may ask to be graded pass/fail.

Comment: It worked, thanks.